C application not building
I'm currently working on an application built using c language. When I tried building the application it built up to some point and then triggered error which says:
Ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
.\out\TP50_debug\examples\DemoCMakedebug\examples\DemoCMakefiles\mainappDemoCMakefiles\mainapp_flash.dir\Applicationdir\Application\source\main.c.obj
The system cannot find the file specified

I tried deleting searching for the above file

Did you add an exclusion to your AV?

Please what is AV?

"Anti virus" probably.

I'll check that

Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Your question severely lacks a [mcve], which would probably also give you a solution on the way.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
